# Running code after a user creates an event - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently using on a bot `@client.event` to check for message commands using `async def on_message(message)`, however I have an issue with finding documentation on triggering an event (code) when a user creates an event (calendar event) for others to join. Is there currently a way to do this in *`discord.py`* like `on_event_creation`?

Comment: i think this is what you're looking for https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=schedule#scheduled-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you look at [scheduled events](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=schedule#scheduled-events) in the event reference, there's an event for when scheduled events are created, [`on_scheduled_event_create`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=schedule#discord.on_scheduled_event_create)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.